# React router history.push() not working from history.listen()

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

In my React application I'm using `react-router-dom` for routing. I have a custom `history` object that I pass in to my `Router` (not `BrowserRouter`) object so I can configure a listen handler on the history object.

```
import { createBrowserHistory } from 'history';
import auth from './auth';

const history = createBrowserHistory();

history.listen((location) => {
  if(location.pathname !== '/login'){
    if(!auth.getToken()){
      history.push('/login');
    }
  }
});

export default history
```

This has worked fine for the past few months, however, after recently updating my `node_modules`, all of a sudden the push inside the `listen` function does not cause an update to the DOM (but changes the URL).

I have no idea what is causing this, and I'm using `history.push` as the sole means of navigating throughout the rest of the app, which is still working, so I don't know why it doesn't work from this file.

Even importing the history object in other .js files that are not a part of my React component tree can call `history.push` and have it update.

Any help is appreciated!

Edit: My `react-router-dom` package version is `^4.4.0-alpha.0`, and React `16.4.0`

Comment: What happens if you write `setTimeout(() => history.push('/login'), 0);`?

Comment: That works! What's the issue?

Comment: I'm not quite sure. Letting everything that is in the execution queue be run before pushing the new history seems like a good idea, but I don't know enough about how `history` is implemented to say why it's needed now. Might be worth opening an issue in the `history` issue tracker with a reproducible example?

Comment: Right, I'll look more in to it. Regardless, thanks so much for your swift reply!

Comment: @Tholle, post your answer so the OP can check it off.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks Tholle for the answer:

My problem was fixed by replacing every `history.push()` with `setTimeout(() => history.push(), 0);`